# How to 'snapshot' my windows drive or full reverse changes?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm not sure if that is possible, and I'm almost sure that Windows System Restore isn't what I need.

I'm trying to run Tensorflow GPU in my windows PC and since this isn't the place for it, I will spare you the trouble of reading all the issues I've runned into so far. However, you should know that there are several different versions of Microsoft Visual C++, nVidia Drivers, CUDA, cuDNN, that should be installed and the "proper combination" doesn't always work for everyone.

**What I'm looking for is a way to take a snapshot of my drive, just after windows clean install. So I can try different versions and combinations of those things and if they don't work, I could just reverse to the snapshot and try again, without worrying that a previous install is causing an issue with the new one.**

I've tried System Restore, but saw that files from Microsoft Visual C++ were still in their directory after the restore, so those files could cause issues with other installations, also it makes me unsure of what else is kept.

Comment: You want to install a Virtual Machine.

Comment: @DourHighArch Not really, can't use my GPU through a VM (for tensorflow at least). But I'm looking for something that works like a VM snapshot, as close as possible.